# Conditionally apply ssh-config

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I have to ssh through a bastion host to get at my AWS instances and services. I setup my ssh config to automatically tunnel through the bastion to get to any of the ip addresses in the range for my stuff.

That's great when I'm working from home, but when I'm in the office, the network there has direct access without needing the bastion host.

Is there a way, using the ssh-config file, to apply things conditionally based on my local ip range or what network I'm connected to, etc?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.